# How to implement Styles into Xamarin.Forms well?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

With control level styling I do not need to worry about adding a line of code for every control on every page.

**Style Class**

```
public static class Styles
{
    #region "Entry"
    public static readonly Style Entry_Standard = new Style(typeof(Entry))
    {
        new Setter {Property = Xamarin.Forms.Entry.BackgroundColorProperty,     Value = Color.Red }
    };
    #endregion
}
```

**Custom Control**

```
public class Custom_Entry : Entry
{
   public Custom_Entry()
    {
        this.Style = Styles.Entry_Standard;
    }
}
```

All of the example documentation from Xamarin though appears to favor setting styles as a property at the page level after object creation either through a page resource or static class reference.

Is there a valid reason for this or is it just that the short examples do not bother to abstract away control styles?

Comment: have you read the docs on Global styles?  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/

Comment: Thank you Jason. Mia Culpa, I have not looked at the Xamarin Documentation since early 2015 it has come a long way.

Comment: I have used liked that with client projects and it is working excellent!

Comment: I still prefer to set style to the custom control so that I do not have to set another property in XAML for each control but the documentation certainly covers many options for global, inherited and dynamic styling options.